# Can I do something with a missing blob without a broken link or a mention in log?

Tags: git

[How to recover a corrupted blob object](https://git.github.io/htmldocs/howto/recover-corrupted-blob-object.html) gives some steps to deal with a missing blob. But in my case (`744284d782d815410d196c4d617ec9b19ca1125d` is the missing blob's hash):

```
alexey@DESKTOP-41AVESA:~/shaka/popmenu$ git fsck --full | grep -C 5 744284d782d815410d196c4d617ec9b19ca1125d
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (442531/442531), done.
dangling commit 03053416ad7b5a26c9bcf9ce351dace8895f9a56
dangling commit b80b64f65a0c5f8a0b08a62f0096e23df2e79d00
dangling commit 490d44f6aa543fd68291cdede26446977893e02d
dangling blob bc10c48bc5f281138afbb3208d31b03471297aaa
dangling commit 8f26b49b1351a9e210e9452a665b5282c2a20b96
missing blob 744284d782d815410d196c4d617ec9b19ca1125d
dangling commit 635054a0d41dd8c559b38ec16b88248c1d1aa142
dangling commit 2e51947be3e30c87bd6d16974bc2b5f05514bad3
dangling commit 3e6af4ece515b441c3b1a59a296e77f124a54208
dangling commit 198134d284effaecdd50910e1b02c1425a5429a5
dangling commit 1a944480079661db8359c613df4bfeb858463e52
Verifying commits in commit graph: 100% (29687/29687), done.
```

doesn't show anything which refers to the missing blob. The other suggestion is

> (Btw, you could have ignored the fsck, and started with doing a git log --raw --all and just looked for the sha of the missing object (4b9458b..) in that whole thing. It’s up to you - Git does have a lot of information, it is just missing one particular blob version.

but `git log --raw --all | grep -C 5 744284d782d815410d196c4d617ec9b19ca1125d` doesn't give any output at all. So can I find why Git thinks this blob should exist in the first place?

Comment: There is probably a tree object pointing to it.

Answer (score 2):

A blob could be referenced by a tree in most cases, or by a tag in very few cases. If a blob has just been created by `git add $file`, then it's referenced by nothing.

To list all tags,

```
git for-each-ref refs/tags
# Or
git tag
```

To find what object a tag `foo` points to,

```
git rev-parse foo^{}
```

To list all tree objects,

```
git cat-file --batch-check='%(objectname) %(objecttype)' --batch-all-objects | grep tree
```

To list all blobs a tree `bar` uses,

```
git ls-tree -r bar | grep blob
```

You can parse all tags and trees to see if the missing blob is referenced by any of them. I am not sure if `git fsck --full` reports the missing objects in a submodule.